# Data flow visualization

Tags: visualization

Can someone recommend a library that will provide an interactive web based visualization of data flow.  I have x nodes with flow lines connecting them. I need a way to dynamically create a flow diagram with the ability to click on the nodes and lines to bring up information.

Any input appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1):

See http://neyric.github.com/wireit/docs/:

> WireIt is an open-source javascript library, to create full-web graph
>   editors for dataflow applications, visual programming languages,
>   graphical modeling, or graph editors.